# Inductance values over the frequency

Tags: rf, inductor, inductance, high-frequency

Does inductance vary over frequency in passive components.
Consider a Coax cable for example, does the inductance value change as a function of frequency, lets say from 5GHz to 100GHz, does the inductance value ever change?

*My understanding is no, inductor values and capacitor values are not a function of frequency but are a function of their physical character.

Comment: Inductance and capacitance are both parametric once packaged, and their values will vary  as the voltage across them and the current through them  varies

Comment: @EMFields. 'Eddy' currents and dielectric leakage also change with frequency and current, but I was not sure the OP wanted us to 'split-hairs' over such details, as we would be including unknown and/or out-of-range parameters.

Comment: @EMFields. I do not understand your comment involving soldering irons, as I have been using them  for 45 years. AS for the splitting hairs issue, that is why I directed the OP to read existing data and charts on impedance, which is a complex subject to put into words. Manufacturers of inductors, capacitors and RF cable offer the fine details of response to frequency sweeps, etc. These help remove some of the 'ambiguities'.

Answer (score 4):

> Does inductance vary over frequency in passive components. Consider a Coax cable for example, does the inductance value change as a function of frequency, lets say from 5GHz to 100GHz, does the inductance value ever change?

Yes, for just about any practical component, the effective inductance will change with frequency.

A coaxial cable is not an easy example to deal with. You should rather be considering it as a transmission line rather than a lumped inductor or inductor/capacitor network. So I'll leave that aside.

Instead consider an inductive coil. Any real coil has *interwinding capacitance*, caused by electric field between adjacent coils of the inductor, and modeled (in a simplified way) as a capacitor in parallel with the idealized inducutor. Above some frequency, the interwinding capacitance will tend to dominate the behavior of the device, causing the reactance to be negative and decreasing with frequency rather than positive and increasing.

Similarly, practical capacitors nearly always have lead inductance. This acts as an inductor in series with the idealized capacitor. Above some frequency (often specified as *series resonance frequency* in capacitor datasheets), the lead inductance tends to dominate the device behavior resulting in positive reactance increasing with frequency rather than negative and decreasing.

The frequencies where these effects become important range from kilohertz to gigahertz depending on the device construction, and you will want to be aware of them when choosing components in your designs.

Furthermore, even if you neglect these geometrical parasitic effects, you'll find that the critcial parameters (permeability of inductor cores and permittivity of capacitor dielectrics) also vary over frequency due to the resonances of the molecules producing the magnetization or polarization that determines those quantities. This will cause the inductance or capacitance of the device to vary (at least slightly) with frequency.

Comment: Regarding your first example of inductive coil, I understand how the capacitance between coil winding might begin to dominate as frequency increases, however, I don't think their values ever increase. Their effect starts dominating after a certain frequency but their value surely can't change, am I correct on this. The only thing that I understand is the changes to permeability and permittivity, which ultimately change capacitance and inductance.

Comment: The capacitance and inductance of the model with parasitics don't change, but the effective inductance (\$X/(2\pi{}f)\$) of the whole device does change.

Answer (score -2):

You have answered your own question, which is NO. An exception would be resistors that have a 'cold' value and a increased resistance when hot. Inductors and capacitors do not change value (ideally) unless the device is being driven outside of normal working parameters, or they are stressed to the point of damage. What does change with frequency is impedance. You will find many answers about impedance on this forum and on the web.