# How does PWM frequency influence the inductance of a DC motor?

Tags: pwm, inductance, brushed-dc-motor

I have read in [this white paper](https://www.portescap.com/en/resources/motor-specifications-and-literature/white-papers/understanding-the-effect-of-pwm-when-controlling-a-brushless-dc-motor) that "Since the motor inductance varies depending on the PWM frequency, at typical PWM frequency of 50 kHz, the inductance may decrease to as low as 70% of the catalog value."

Does inductance decrease at higher frequencies? And why?

Comment: See  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235978/inductance-values-over-the-frequency

Comment: Many core materials reduce their magnetic permeability with rising frequency.